# External scripts not working in Windows Phone App 8.1

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-phone-8, webview

I've added a WebView into my project. If I navigate to the html file that contains external javascript files they don't work. Bit if I write the javascript code hardcoded into the html file it works properly.

Here is the html portion:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="testjs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="abcd"></div>
    <br/>
    hello! this is a simple html block. 
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript portion:

```
document.getElementById("abcd").innerHTML = "New text!";
```

When I open the webview it shows

`hello! this is a simple html block.`,

but if the javascript code worked it would show

`New Test!
hello! this is a simple html block.`

Here is the folder structure:

[image]

Comment: your code works fine to me [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/4ahdk0v1/)

Comment: post the full code of the testjs.js file please

Comment: My testjs.js file is that short. But it doesn't work in WebView. I think I've problem with relative path. What should be the relative path of the js script  in the html file according to my folder structure?

Comment: the relative path should be "./testjs.js "

Comment: Did you mean to write `src="./testjs.js"`? I tried with that. Even I tried with `src="/testjs.js"` , `src="problem_page/testjs.js"`  

None of them worked! :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

src="testjs.js" is correct. The issue is not related to the path.

[Update 1]

Your code should work as we usually do for web development. But seems we need to make sure the html element used in the script has been initialized, so we have to put the  to the end of the body element. Please try the following html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="abcd">a</div>
    <br />
    hello! this is a simple html block.

    <script type="text/javascript" src="testjs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Update 2]

Also check if you have changed the **build action** for `testjs.js` to content. go to **Solution Explorer** -> right click on `testjs.js` -> **Properties** -> change **Build Action** to **Content.** That will make sure the `.js` file will be deployed as part of you app.

Comment: I think injecting javascript into the webview is not a good idea when it is pretty big in size. And I guess we can include external javascript files. In this sample app they used external javascripts:  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7

Comment: I think you are right. And I got the code work on my side. To avoid misleading others, I changed my post.

Comment: It seems that you created the project as WebView App for windows phone, right? I created my project as Universal C# app. Actually the `test.html` page is navigated from `Pages/SelfStudyNS/OnlineTest.xaml.cs` class. I'm not sure whether the straightforward html app like webviews work in this case or not. Here is the structure of the solution explorer: http://postimg.org/image/5e1r1yfxb/

Comment: I just created another test project based on your structure. check http://1drv.ms/1ARDmJ6. And one more thing I want to call out is have you modified the build action for testjs.js to content? go to solution explorer-> right click on testjs.js->properties->change build action to content. I also updated this in my reply.

Comment: Now it works after I change the build action from the javascript Properties. Many many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

WebView msdn page suggests that for security reasons you can not link to local  content except for:

> However, you can still link to HTML content in the app package using the ms-appx-web scheme, and to web content using the http and https URI schemes.

So you should be able to link to your script file using `ms-appx-web:///testjs.js` url.