# Is it allowed to include external javascript files in the html file of a webview in Windows Phone 8.1 app?

Tags: javascript, c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, webview

I've created a weview in my `C#` and `XAML` app that navigates to a html page. The html page includes some javascript files, but the javascript files don't work in the webview. So my question is: **Is it allowed to include external javascript files in the html file of a webview in Windows Phone 8.1 app?**

I've discussed the problems I faced to include external js files here: [External scripts not working in Windows Phone App 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986710/external-scripts-not-working-in-windows-phone-app-8-1)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is allowed to include external `javascript` files in the `html` file of a webview. In this sample external javascript is included: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7

To run external `javascript` files in any html file the **Build Action** property of that `javascript` must be set as **Content**.

Comment: you can point to the code in the above mentioned link, that specifies HTML referencing external javascript? and the way that it should be tackled.